# Is it possible to select or highlight a substring of text within a text box using watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm relatively new to ruby and watir but am trying to build a ruby script that will select a given subset of a string out of a text box.

Example given the string:

```
"Here Here!"
```

I would like to be able to select the second instance of "Here"

I've been using watir-webdriver/extensions/select_text.rb thinking that I could use this to accomplish my goal but as far as I can tell it can only selected the first matching text of an element. I was hoping for something that could take in a beginning and ending index and select only those characters.  Does anyone know if something like that exists in ruby?

Comment: You'll need a bit more information. Can you capture the entire text? If that's the case, this is not a [tag:watir] question, it's likely a [tag:regex] question instead. Also, can you be more specific about how you identify what you want to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the text in a variable.

Lets say your variable is `test_string = "Here Here!"`

Now split it using `.split` method like this

`words = test_string.split(" ")`

`words` is an array whose contents are `Here` at `index 0` and `Here!` at `index 1` (Array in any language starts from zero).

Now you can call any instance you wish. If you want second, get it like this:

`puts words [1]` this will give you `Here!`

```
test_string = "Here Here!"
words = test_string.split(" ")
puts words [1]
```

OR

```
test_string = @browser.___your_locator__.text
words = test_string.split(" ")
puts words [1]
```